# help and example or examples?

Tags: grammatical-number

In the preface to a textbook for teachers, I saw the following sentence and am curious as to why "example" is not in the plural.

1. In the first edition of this book I acknowledged the help and **example** that I had received from a number of people, especially...

Obviously, there is more than one (teaching) example in the book.

Comment: well, you wouldn't say 'helps'

Comment: @ "help" is different. "Example" is a countable noun, and in the absence of an article or possessive, we 'd expect "examples".

Comment: @Apollyon *Example* is, in some senses, also non-countable. *He was a fine example to his children*.

Comment: @WS2: Wouldn't *"They were a fine example to their children"* be more persuasive?

Comment: @WS2 Your example has "example" preceded by an indefinite article, which is lacking in my original example.

Comment: I tend to agree with @WS2 that the example is likely meant to refer to the people themselves, rather than to examples provided for the book. The wording seems odd though.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Yes. I see your point. And I tend to share the OP's concern that in the quoted sentence *example* is not in the plural. That is not to say, however, that there are not contexts in which *example* is  non-countable, as in *The teachers all taught by example*. That may explain the preface-writer's thinking.

Comment: @Apollyon -- In your example it's preceded by the definite article instead.

Comment: @ It's odd anyway. Even if the "example" refers to people we should emulate, the verb '"received" is unusual with it.

Comment: "Unusual", perhaps, but not really "odd".

Answer (score 1):

'Example' has two meanings. (i) used in text books etc to refer to a problem posed for practice, or to illustrate a concept being explained. It is regularly used as singular and as plural;
(ii) (of a person) acting as a role model, or displaying traits/behaviour that are worthy of emulation

That you refer to (i) above, means you have taken the word to mean practice problem/s where in fact its meaning fits (ii). That is, it refers to *people* and not to textbook content.

You can then gloss the meaning of the passage to be:
"I acknowledge the help [i.e. assistance] and example [i.e.their *role modelling (singular)* in some manner]".

This reading also fits the grammatical construction where *both* the 'help' and 'example' belong to 'the people'. If you grammatically hive off 'example' and impute to it reference to 'example' in the textbook, it gives rise to exactly the problem that you find yourself faced with. Hope this helps.

Comment: 'Example' in the second sense you give is a non-count usage, like 'help'; neither is singular (a property only count noun usages can have) though both are of singular form. / A good answer on ELU contains supporting evidence (eg a dictionary definition, with usage, and examples). Such sources must be attributed.

Comment: can you say "receive the example" in the sense you're arguinig for? If not, the "example" in the original example might mean the other sense.

Answer (score 0):

***Example*** is treated as uncountable and singular when used *in generalised sense to mean action or conduct that induces imitation (‘influence that disposes to imitation’ (Johnson)* (OED).

1653   *I. Walton Compl. Angler 47*   Well, you know what example is able to do.

a1680   *S. Butler Genuine Remains (1759) I. 73*   Example, that imperious Dictator Of all that's good, or bad to human Nature.

a1729   *J. Rogers 19 Serm. (1735) iv. 70*   Example is a Motive of a very prevailing Force on the Actions of Men.

1796   *E. Burke Lett. Peace Regic. France i, in Wks. (1808) VIII. 196*   Example is the school of mankind.

1871   *S. Smiles Character ii. 35*   Example is far more than precept. It is instruction in action.